# Date Formula Field Problem

Tags: formula, formula-field, date

I have two dates fields as **(Procedure_Code_Date__c and Service_Date_To__c )**  on my object.And i want to make a new formula field for if one of the dates is null then other one will populates or if both of them null then createddate will populates my formula field.So i wrote this formula field but it not works. How can i modify this ?

```
> IF( Procedure_Code_Date__c <> Null , Procedure_Code_Date__c , IF( 
    > Service_Date_To__c <> null , Service_Date_To__c, IF( CreatedDate <>
    > null , CreatedDate)))
```

Comment: What is the return type for your Formula field ? and what are the data type for Procedure Code Date and Service Date To fields?

Comment: Make sure all the data types are dateTime type.

Comment: @Sanjay formula fields type is date, also Procedure Code Date and Service Date To field's type is date

Comment: CreatedDate returns dateTime type, if you want your result in 'Date' type then use the DATEVALUE function to convert a date/time value into a date value.

Comment: What is not working? Is there an error saving it (compiler)? Is there an error at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try -

```
IF( NOT(ISBLANK(Procedure_Code_Date__c)) , Procedure_Code_Date__c ,    
IF( NOT(ISBLANK(Service_Date_To__c)), Service_Date_To__c,     
IF( NOT(ISBLANK(CreatedDate),DATEVALUE(CreatedDate),''
     ) )
```

So **CreatedDate** returns value of type **dateTime** and the formula field you are using returns value of type **Date**

**DATEVALUE** function converts the return type of CreatedDate's to data type - Date.

Also using **IsBlank()** is the best practice when you are checking if an expression has a value or not.

Comment: This is a correct answer. A good answer would explain why you made the changes you did and explain why the original formula failed. Please expand, and I will vote up!

Comment: It should be `!ISBLANK` (not blank), your formula returns the field if its blank. Your last IF statement should probably be `IF (!ISBLANK(CreatedDate), DATEVALUE(CreatedDate), null)` so that it returns null

Comment: @BartCotter: Good catch ! I edited my answer +1 for you

Comment: Also, I don't think you need to include condition for createddate. I assume it will be always present since it is a standard field.

Comment: Sanjay answered correctly. Just in case you want to avoid condition for createddate, you can use this formula.    IF(!ISBLANK(Procedure_Code_Date__c),  Procedure_Code_Date__c,IF(!ISBLANK(Service_Date_To__c), Service_Date_To__c,DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)))

Comment: Thank you for your all answers, i am new in this platform so that explanation is good for me, also thank you @Dave for your explanation and formula, i used yours and it is ok.